# Easiest way to populate control without postback?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a `List<Foo>` that is used to create a number of Panels. To each of these panels, I want to tie a javascript function that, when clicked, populates a different Panel with contents from this Foo object. Something like this:

```
Table table = new Table();
        table.Style.Add("width", "100%");
        var foos = _fooManager.OrderedFoos;
        var row = new TableRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < foos.Count; i++)
        {
            row.Cells.Add(CreateButton(foos[i]));
            if (i % 3 == 2)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(row);
                row = new TableRow();
            }
        }
        if (row.Controls.Count > 0)
            table.Rows.Add(row);

        return table;

private TableCell CreateButton(Foo foo)
    {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        Panel panel = new Panel() { CssClass = "tile third color-blue" };
        Label label = new Label() { Text = foo.FooName };
        panel.Controls.Add(label);
        cell.Controls.Add(panel);
        cell.Attributes.Add("data-foo-id", foo.FooID.ToString());
        cell.Attributes.Add("onClick", @"onFooClick(this); return false;");
        return cell;
    }
```

So. How would I go about to display the contents of the Foo object clicked (identifiable through fooID) on a Panel on this same page? I understand how I could accomplish this through an ASP BUtton and a postback, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Can you assign the value as JSON to a Javascript variable then populate with an `onclick` Javascript event?

Comment: use AjaxControlToolkit update panel

Comment: Too broad. Learn Ajax come back when/if you have any issues.

Comment: Anything done without postback is best done purely via client side code. That means that the adding of a button should be worked out in javascript, not in your code behind. Ajax is another possibility, but since you don't mention it, I assume you want the webpage to be selfsufficient without requiring input from the backend. This means javascript-based DOM manipulation. Not saying it can't be done via backend code and Ajax calls, just that it's not as easy to develop if you are able to provide all needed data on the first page load (which, if implemented correctly, will be the only page load).

Comment: @EhsanSajjad reading up on UpdatePanel now.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways.

First (less recommended since can send lots of data to client):
Create all the panel upon load but hidden (style="display:none"). then when the user click on a button respond to this click and show the appropriate panel.

Second:
Load the panel content using ajax and webmethods.

You have a good example here: [ajax and webmethods](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery ajax you can send a request to the server without a postback. your onFooClick will look something like the following

```
function onFooClick(foo){
    //get data-foo-id
    var fooID = $(foo).data("foo-id");
    $.ajax({
        requestType: "get",
        url: "WEBSERVICEURL",
        data: { "fooid": fooID },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#otherPanel").text(data.Name);//or whatever field/data you want to display
    }).fail(function(error){
        alert(error);
    });
}
```

in your WEBSERVICE you fetch the data against the fooID and return the object back (serialized as json)

the `done()` method will receive this data and can display to whatever div/panel you want